# Get attribute from html with jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

There is a

```
<div id="content"> 
      <form id="fm1" class="fm-v clearfix" action="/cas/login;jsessionid=B91535E9EB93313D6FADBA2C63D10EC2" method="post">
</div>
```

How to get the value of the action attribute:

> "/cas/login;jsessionid=B91535E9EB93313D6FADBA2C63D10EC2"

Comment: What have you achieved so far?

Comment: Elements el = doc.select("form[action]");
System.out.println(el);  but it prints the body of this form. But i need only a value

Comment: @MitchellCameron add that to your question - showing your efforts improves your question, by both clarifying what did not work and signalling that you actually tried to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to loop it you can simply call like this:

```
Elements test = doc.select("form");
System.out.println(test.attr("action"));
```

Comment: css selectors should be as specific as possible.  Selecting on tag "form" might not have the desired result if there is more than 1 form.

Comment: @ZackTeater but What OP  has the String which contains only one form right?

Comment: it is, but selecting on a single tag is way too broad.  CSS selectors should be as specific as possible.  Otherwise, the markup you are parsing becomes tightly coupled to other parts of the document.  For instance, the introduction of a new form on the document should not impact my ability to parse the action from the original form.

Comment: anyway Thanks for pointing right direction once again man. i always listen others suggestion if it is right

Answer (score 0):

Select the form tag(s) using [CSS Selectors](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax).  Since you know it is the first `form` in the `div`, you can further drill down using `first().attr(String)`.

```
String action = doc.select("div#content form#fm1").first().attr("action");
System.out.println(action);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Elements test = doc.select("div[id=content]>form[id=fm1]");
for (Element x :test){
    System.out.println(x.attr("action"));
}
```

it is my answer. Thx for all

Comment: Selecting id on tags should be done with #.  See CSS Selectors: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jsoup/515/selectors#t=201607261348421461231&a=remarks